# GRPC address prefix

Tags: grpc

When I use WCF's NETTCP binding endpoint address looks like: `net.tcp://localhost:51111/MyService/`.

When I use Websockets endpoint address looks like: `ws://localhost:port/Esv/ocp` and for secure connection `wss://localhost:port/Esv/ocp`.

Is there any common prefix for gRPC services? Or only `192.168.1.1:51111` is OK since called method is binded to GRPC server by:

```
ServerServiceDefinition.CreateBuilder().AddMethod(_myCommunicationMethodName, CallProcessingMehtod).Build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a grpc service, the URL of the underlying HTTP2 request is determined by the name of the of the service and the method name (as found in the .proto definition). Besides that, there is no "prefix" and using one would be against the recommendations in the gRPC wire protocol spec (more on that in github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/110).

Note that under normal circumstances, you don't need to know the exact URL used by a gRPC method call as this is something that's encapsulated by the gRPC client and server logic.

Comment: My understanding is, that he is talking about URIs and the scheme part of that. He calls that prefix. I also do not understand how the linked go implementation specific issue is related to this question. 

I am also searching for a common scheme that is used for gRPC and allows identifying that a URI is for gRPC not for regular http + html stuff. But as gRPC uses HTTP/2 the correct but not helping solution seems to save such addresses as "http://<grpc-server>/" or create a own scheme like "http.grpc://<grpc-server>"

Comment: Anyone who has ever built a moderately complex web application, especially on infrastructure like kubernetes, would know that life gets much, much harder when you cannot prefix your uri space for a given service. me.com/service1/com.foo and me.com/service9/com.foo being routed to different backends is a pretty commonly used pattern.